# Remove android Button permanently if User wants

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, erase

I am developing an android application in which i have several buttons with some text in them. I used these buttons as tags so that when the application installed these 50 buttons will show on screen as tags. Now what i want is that if a user does not want these tags then they can remove the button permanently. i.e. if their is a tag named "Free Delivery" and user doesnot want this then the user can click on the button and if choose Yes then the button of Free Delivery will be deleted permanently and it will not appear next time when user opens the application.
How to do this?
I have tried this:

```
button1.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
```

but when the user open the app next time then the button again showed up
Please HELP!

Comment: You can add your button programatically and decide whether to add it or not when you start the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the preferences of the user with `SharedPreferences`, it's a way to save information whithout connexion to a database.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) is the Google's documentation for the SharedPreferences.

You can find how to use them in a already resolved question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

An example of how save a preference :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("Name","Alan");
editor.apply();
```

And here how to get it :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String name = preferences.getString("Name", null);
```

Comment: Ok, you can find a lot of information with the second link I gave you, but if you don't understand, ask questions here, I will try to help you :)

Comment: I tried this but Iam confused what to write here in the value tag   because I am not passing string value instead i want to check next time that whether that button was deleted by user or not so what to pass in the value?editor.putString("Name", );

Comment: You can also put int or boolean in shared preferences like this : 
`editor.putBoolean("tag1", false);`

Comment: so when i delete the button then i call shared preference and pass this tag as false?

Comment: when you do the action that means _delete the button_, you saved the sharedPreference for this tag at false, and next time when you display the buttons, you check if the sharedPreference for this button is false or true. If it's false, you set it at View.GONE, else View.VISIBLE

Comment: you made it ? it is ok ?

Comment: Ok great ! Glad I could help you :)

Comment: Looking forward to take help from genious like you in future too :) email id if u allowed me? :)

Answer (score 3):

store that button value in `DB` or `SharedPreference` and check everytime user opens your `application`.

if user doesn't want button1 , store that value in `Database` or `Sharedpreference` and check if `button1` is present then hide it from screen.

```
if(button1 value in db/preference)
    button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```